# Type Script paths not working. Even after setting up "baseUrl" property in tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, feathersjs, tsconfig, absolute-path

when I try to `import {Model, Mongoose} from 'mongoose'`, it actually looks for `./src/mongoose.ts` that's the file generated by feathers by default. this problem only arises when I use the below property in tsconfig.ts.

`"baseUrl": "./src"`

I have to use this property in my project and have to avoid that problem too?

when I try to set this property for absolute paths in tsconfig.json. I get an error from file `/src/models/users.model.ts`.

line generating the error:

```
import { Model, Mongoose } from 'mongoose';
```

error generated:-

> error TS2614: Module '"mongoose"' has no exported member 'Mongoose'. Did you mean to use 'import Mongoose from "mongoose"' instead?

Comment: tsconfig file{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // "moduleResolution": "node",
    // "baseUrl": "./src",
    // "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["test"]
  // "include": ["src"]
}

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
"baseUrl": "src" and "include": ["src/*.ts"]
```

Comment: when I try to set "baseUrl": "./src", its trying to resolve node-modules folder in ./src

Comment: what about just "src"?

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@services/*": ["services/*"],
      "@models/*": ["models/*"],
      "*": ["../*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test"
  ],
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}